# Is it possible to have different legend background colors for different data rows in Google bar chart, without breaking the chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, data-visualization

See the example code:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Mac');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Score');
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
    data.addRows([
       ['Mac model 12', 200, 'color: #8bba30; opacity: 0.75;'],
       ['Another Mac Model', 110, 'color: #ffcc33; opacity: 0.75;'],
    ]);
    var options = {
        title: '',
        width: 500,
        height: data.getNumberOfRows() * 40 + 100,
        hAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 255,
            ticks: [0, 75, 150, 255],
            textPosition: 'out',
            side: 'top'
        },
        series: {
            0: { axis: 'Mac' },
            1: { axis: 'Score' }
        },
        chartArea: {
            top: 0,
            bottom: 50,
            right: 50,
            left: 150
        },
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        fontSize: 12,
        bar: {groupWidth: '75%'},
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('apple_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

See, there are different colors for different bars. But I want different color and/or background-color for different legends on left side.

Can someone help me with this please?

I found following answer, [Is it possible to show each legend in different color in google pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584349/is-it-possible-to-show-each-legend-in-different-color-in-google-pie-chart).

But it suggests on breaking down the chart(i.e. to draw separate charts for each rows), which is not desirable as there are large numbers of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by *breaking the chart*, but...

You can modify the chart svg, once the `'ready'` event fires.

This example changes the color of the legend text to match the bar color.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var colors = ['#8bba30', '#ffcc33'];
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Mac');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Score');
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
  data.addRows([
     ['Mac model 12', 200, 'color: ' + colors[0] + '; opacity: 0.75;'],
     ['Another Mac Model', 110, 'color: ' + colors[1] + '; opacity: 0.75;'],
  ]);
  var options = {
      title: '',
      width: 500,
      height: data.getNumberOfRows() * 40 + 100,
      hAxis: {
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue: 255,
          ticks: [0, 75, 150, 255],
          textPosition: 'out',
          side: 'top'
      },
      series: {
          0: { axis: 'Mac' },
          1: { axis: 'Score' }
      },
      chartArea: {
          top: 0,
          bottom: 50,
          right: 50,
          left: 150
      },
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      fontSize: 12,
      bar: {groupWidth: '75%'},
  };

  var chartContainer = document.getElementById('apple_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartContainer);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var labels = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var colorIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      if (labels[i].getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') {
        labels[i].setAttribute('fill', colors[colorIndex]);
        colorIndex++;
      }
    }
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="apple_div"></div>
```

As for background color, [SVG elements do not have background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873128/5090771)
so you would have to draw your own `rect` for that...

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, in giving the answer. It saved me lots of effort and I must up-vote your answer to do the least.