# Color Themes in Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I am pretty familiar with Google Charts but was never able to find one thing. You can change the colors of your columns or bars or pie pieces or whatever in a couple of ways but essentially it comes down to something like this:

```
chart.draw(data, {
  width: 400,
  height: 240,
  title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'],
  is3D: true
});
```

Does anyone know how I can apply a "color theme"? Meaning, make the chart all bluish, or reddish or orangish. The hard coded color values work OK if you have a fixed data set but I am working on dynamic data sets. Sometimes I will have 3 series and sometimes 15, and I would like a way to set a chart color style/theme.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615002/given-an-rgb-value-how-do-i-create-a-tint-or-shade

Comment: no option to _apply a "color theme"_ -- in addition to `colors`, you can use a `style` [Column Role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) -- you could also change the color of other chart elements, such as the legend labels, on the `'ready'` event --> [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36769078/5090771)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you anyway